# iOS define touchable areas of an object, confine touches to subviews of self

Tags: ios, uigesturerecognizer, uitouch, touchesbegan

I have a subclassed UIView I'll call customView. I would like enable touches so users can manipulate subviews, which have gesture recognizers and other controls, but the view itself I would like to not be touchable so that views drawn below the view will still be touchable. In other words customView will be drawn on top of other views in the app, but I still want the views below to be touchable, while allowing touches on subviews of customView.

I've tried to use touchesBegan like so but this does not work. Any ideas? Thanks for reading!

```
-(void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {
    UITouch *touch = [[event allTouches] anyObject];

//I've tagged the views that I want to be touchable.
    if ([touch view].tag == 1000 || [touch view].tag == 2000 || [touch view].tag == 3000) {
        self.userInteractionEnabled = YES;
    } else {
        self.userInteractionEnabled = NO;
    }
}
```

Comment: So you want cusomView nontouchable and ,view below cusomview have to be touchable right?

Comment: @Dilip I want to "mask" / exclude touches from areas of the view, except in certain sub views.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you need to do is implement the following method in your customView:

```
- (UIView *)hitTest:(CGPoint)point withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
{
    //check if one of the subviews was hit, if so forward the touch event to it
    for (UIView *view in self.subviews){
        if (CGRectContainsPoint(view.frame, point))
            return view;
    }

    // use this to pass the 'touch' upward in case no subviews trigger the touch
    return [super hitTest:point withEvent:event];
}
```

Comment: @Mrwolfy have you tried my answer, I am curious to know if it worked for you, because I had a similar problem where this method worked for me, but it wasn't exactly identical to your case..

Answer (score 0):

Then add those subview upper to your customview.other vice your customview should not let them touche.and put custom view to below those subview so none other area then your selected subview will be touchable.